# Error when parsing Html using Jsoup

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup

I want parsing html site and get a string value. But i receive error when parsing div class.

```
<div class="content clear">
```

I wrote above code but i received error.

```
try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://tvrehberi.hurriyet.com.tr/program-detay/308271/deli-deli-olma").get();

List<String> saatItem = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Element  iterable : doc.getElementsByClass("content&clear")) {
            saatItem.add(iterable.text());

        }
catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This error cause class have blank character. If class value hasn't blank character, code runs perfectly.
How can i solve this problem ?

Error logs :

```
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.htmlparsingtutorial/com.example.htmlparsingtutorial.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:408)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:393)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:159)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:148)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at com.example.htmlparsingtutorial.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:90)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
02-06 00:18:53.770: E/AndroidRuntime(28775):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this exception is thrown if you run networkcode in the main thread.
The solution is to run your task as an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

btw. please test this code, on PC it works:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://tvrehberi.hurriyet.com.tr/program-detay/308271/deli-deli-olma").get();

List<String> saatItem = new ArrayList<String>();

for( Element element : doc.select("div[class=content clear]"))
{
    saatItem.add(element.text());
}
```