# Jsoup doesnt find the specified element

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to write a little android program (don't mind the messiness) that shows the last "Did you know?" from Wikipedia. But for some reason Jsoup doesn't find it.

What is the problem?

---

Part of the code:

```
Document document = null;
try {
    document = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Mathematics/Did_you_know/1").get();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//Document document = Jsoup.parse("test.html");
if (document != null) {
    Element element = document.select("div#mw-content-text").first();
    if (element == null) {
        message = "empty";
    } else {
        message = element.html();
    }
}
```

Part of the wikipedia source code:

```
<div id="mw-content-text" lang="en" dir="ltr" class="mw-content-ltr"><p>...that outstanding mathematician <a href="/wiki/Grigori_Perelman" title="Grigori Perelman">Grigori Perelman</a> was offered a <a href="/wiki/Fields_Medal" title="Fields Medal">Fields Medal</a> in 2006, in part for his proof of the <a href="/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture" title="Poincaré conjecture">Poincaré conjecture</a>, which he declined?</p>
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Mathematics/Did_you_know/1

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine on a desktop. Check your android settings according to internet access rights. Also it's a good idea to check where's the real problem.

**Some hints:**

- replace `e.printStackTrace();` with a logger
- write the value of `message` variable to a logger too
- are you using an [AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718109/error-when-parsing-html-using-jsoup/14719224#14719224)?
- Are there any errors, exception or something similar?

Comment: The JSoup.connect() doesn't throw any error. But when I try to do something with the value of message the program crashes (NullPointerException). And no, I'm not using ASyncTask, the code above is in the onCreate() method.