# Using Jsoup to extract text from specific class

Tags: java, android, jsoup

i'm trying to work with a little android at the moment.
Before all the hate - Yes I have tried searching and found answers related to mine but I simply couldnt get mine to work with the way they did it :/.
I have found out that Jsoup is rather good for parsing data from HTML to use in an app.

So I have trying to recieve data from here [Krak](http://mobil.krak.dk/)

So when I enter the input for a number lets say "86202710"
The link will be [Number link](http://mobil.krak.dk/h/#companyResult&searchWord=86202710)

I have then tried to extract the name of the owner of the given number which is "Jens Fisker Automobiler A/S". But I cant seem to get this text out into my textview.
Hope you guys can guide me alittle...
I get an exception "NetworkOnMainThreadException" - AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork"

Here is the code I have written to the method for extracting the owner of the number

```
public void getData() throws IOException{
    URL url = new URL("http://mobil.krak.dk/h/#companyResult&searchWord=86202710");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
    Element content = doc.select("p[header bold]").first();
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    text.setText(content.text());

}
```

Comment: AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork <-- that looks like some kind of security restriction, doesn't it?

Comment: Yea I tried following the answer from here stackoverflow.com/questions/6074365/… Now the app doesnt crash but I get UnknownHostException saying that no address is associated with the hostname? – So I tried to add the permission to let the app access the internet - yeah I know dumb I didnt do it before :S..
But now I receive a nullPointerException as if the text is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your networkcode in a [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) on Android. Everything else will fail.

See here: [Error when parsing Html using Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718109/error-when-parsing-html-using-jsoup/14719224)

- Do you connect through a proxy?
- Please check if you have the settings like posted here: [Android NetworkOnMainThreadException inside of AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398418/android-networkonmainthreadexception-inside-of-asynctask)

Btw. better use `connect()` method than `parse()` for such connections:

```
public void getData() throws IOException{
    // You can use a simple string as url
    final String url = "http://mobil.krak.dk/h/#companyResult&searchWord=86202710";
    // Connect to url and parse it's content
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); // Timeout is set to 3 Sec. per default

    // Everything else stays same

    Element content = doc.select("p[header bold]").first();
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    text.setText(content.text());

}
```